# Handling Exceptions From Different Parts of the Code

Tags: apex, error, exception, design-patterns

I've got a case where different parts of the code need to handle exceptions differently, and was wondering if there is a pattern or a recommendation for approaching the problem. Let me explain exactly the issue.

***THE CONTEXT***

I am writing an invokable method that accepts a list of requests (from flows), and for each request it needs to:

1. generate a csv from a report
2. send an email to a user with the csv attached
3. update a few records (some subscriptions that were involved in the report)

***THE CODE***

I have implemented this in code by looping over the requests and executing each bullet from the list noted in different methods:

```
    for(AXARequest request:requests){

                emailTemplateId=request.isNewAccountsOption ? newAccountsTemplate.Id : existingAcountsTemplate.Id;
            
                Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment=generateCsvAttachment(request.isNewAccountsOption,[SELECT Id,DeveloperName,Name FROM Report WHERE DeveloperName=:AXA_REPORT_NAME LIMIT 1]);
                
                sendEmail(emailTemplateId,attachment,request,response);

                if(request.isNewAccountsOption){
            
                    markSubscriptionsAsExported();
                }

                responses.add(response);
        }

        return responses;
```

***THE PROBLEM***

I need to handle exceptions in a way that:

1. If any exception is thrown by the area of code that implements any bullet point in the list, I need to return a 'ERROR' response
2. If sending an email fails (bullet point no. 2), I need to execute specific actions (show a notification in the flow)
3. If updating a few records fails (bullet point no. 3), I need to execute some other actions (send an email with the records that failed to update)

How do I approach handling the exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If any exception is thrown by the area of code that implements any bullet point in the list, I need to return a 'ERROR' response

You'll want a try-catch inside the loop:

```
for(AXARequest request:requests){
    try {
        emailTemplateId=request.isNewAccountsOption ? newAccountsTemplate.Id : existingAcountsTemplate.Id;
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment=generateCsvAttachment(request.isNewAccountsOption,[SELECT Id,DeveloperName,Name FROM Report WHERE DeveloperName=:AXA_REPORT_NAME LIMIT 1]);
        sendEmail(emailTemplateId,attachment,request,response);
        if(request.isNewAccountsOption){
            markSubscriptionsAsExported();
        }
        responses.add(response);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        // Do whatever you need to do here, e.g.
        responses.add(e.getMessage());
    }
}
return responses;
```

> If sending an email fails (bullet point no. 2), I need to execute specific actions (show a notification in the flow)

As above, it's a matter of try-catch blocks, or using `Email.sendMessage(messages, false)` (where false is the allOrNone attribute, allowing partial success on email send).

> If updating a few records fails (bullet point no. 3), I need to execute some other actions (send an email with the records that failed to update)

Again, using allOrNone=false is desirable here. You can then safely handle partial updates.

---

Your code has a problem, though. This code will fail if more than 10 records are present in a flow; you can only call Messaging.sendEmail ten times in a transaction. You need to bulkify your code, as outlined in this [document](https://developer.salesforce.com/wiki/apex_code_best_practices).

This includes building the messages in a loop, processing the response, then doing any updates.

I'm going to write this as "pseudo-code", meaning it definitely won't compile, but it should give you an idea of what you're trying to do.

```
Report axaReport = [SELECT Id,DeveloperName,Name FROM Report WHERE DeveloperName=:AXA_REPORT_NAME LIMIT 1];
Boolean shouldMarkAsExported = false;
Messaging.Email[] messages = new Messaging.Email[0];
for(AXARequest request: requests) {
  emailTemplateId=request.isNewAccountsOption ? newAccountsTemplate.Id : existingAcountsTemplate.Id;
  Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment=generateCsvAttachment(request.isNewAccountsOption,axaReport);
  messages.add(generateMessage(emailTemplateId, attachment, request, response));
  shouldMarkAsExported |= request.isNewAccountsOption;
}
sendEmail(messages);
if(shouldMarkAsExported) {
  markSubscriptionsAsExported();
}
```

Additional work might also be necessary. The main point is that you need to just use appropriate try-catch and/or allOrNone=false handling.